# Scala / Play2 - dynamic constraints based on checkbox value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I hava a template that creates a checkbox and a text input field:

```
@helper.checkbox(inputForm("live"), 'checked -> true, 'onclick -> "hideTextFields()")
@helper.inputText(inputForm("target"), 'disabled -> true)
```

When unchecking the checkbox, the text fields get visible (and vice versa). This is done in a javascript function called hideTextFields().

Now, in the controller I need to have a constraint, that makes the text input field mandatory as soon as the checkbox is unchecked.

I have a mapping:

```
"live" -> boolean
"target" -> nonEmptyText
```

but this always requires the target to be specified.

How can I achieve dynamic constraints for the text input field based on the checkbox's state. Play is version 2.3.4.

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Stupid tag... choose better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the verifying methods that are on Mapping, which you get back from `tuple()` and `mapping()`

Simple example:

```
val sample = Form(
  tuple(
    "checkbox" -> boolean,
    "text" -> text
  ).verifying(
    "If checkbox checked text cannot be empty", 
    (tuple) => !tuple._1 || tuple._2.nonEmpty)
  )
```

You can find another example under "Defining ad-hoc constraints" in the play framework docs: [The playframework docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms)